# NodeJS | Decode HTTP response data of windows-1253 format

Tags: node.js, encoding, utf-8, http-headers, content-type

**Problem**

I use axios (that is not important, any alternative is ok) to make my HTTP calls to an external API.

When I do these HTTP calls via Postman to the API directly, I get this header at the API call response:

```
{ ..., Content-Type: application/json; charset=windows-1253, ... }
```

I do these HTTP calls via my NodeJS app like this:

```
router.get('/data',
    async (req, res) => {
        try {
            let customers = await axios
                .post(URL, {
                    ...
                })
            res.send(customers.data)
        } catch (error) {
            res.send({ error: error })
        }
    }
)
```

and when I call it from Postman I get this header at the API call response:

```
{ ..., Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8, ... }
```

Pay attention that in the first case, the charset is (correctly) windows-1253, wherein the second case it is utf-8

**Question**

How can I set the charset to the response to be windows-1253 **OR** is there any way to decode utf-8 into windows-1253 in nodejs?

I found out about [iconv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv), but as stated [in this repository](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) I have to install external tools to use it which is not my favorite think to do, so I would appreciate any alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to decode into ISO-8859-7 like this:

```
        let customers = await axios.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {
                ...
            },
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            reponseEncoding: 'binary'
        });
        const decoder = new TextDecoder('ISO-8859-7');
        let decodedCustomers = decoder.decode(customers.data)
```

Comment: I am very glad :D I can feel your joy, should be the same as mines when I found out xD. Άντε με το καλό <3